# Запуск базы данных из терминала Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ubuntu

Новичек в базах данных. Уставил MySQL, ввел в терминал `mysql -u root -p`, далее ввожу пароль. Возникает ошибка:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Содержимое файла `my.cnf`:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по сообщению об ошибке у вас не запущен сервер MySQL, проверьте висит ли в процессах mysqld

```
ps uax | grep mysqld
```

Если его нет, попробуйте запустить при помощи команды

```
sudo service mysql start
```

При помощи команды service вы можете управлять сервером MySQL, например, останавливать

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

или рестартовать

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Если попытка старта сервера не приводит к результатам, он не появляется среди процессов, следует обратиться к логам в /var/log/mysql, возможно там сообщается какая-то дополнительная информация о том, почему сервер не может стартовать.

Проверьте где расположен файл сокета, для этого откройте конфигурационный файл /etc/mysql/my.cnf, найдите секцию [mysqld] и директиву socket. Обычно она указывает на /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock. Если у вас путь не совпадает с тем, о котором сообщает утилита mysql, попробуйте указать его явно

```
mysql -u root -p --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**UPDATE**

Если сокет вообще отключен, тогда взаимодействие осуществляется через сеть, в этом случае в качестве хоста следует указывать IP-адрес 127.0.0.1

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

Есть два способа соединения с MySQL-сервером: через сокет и через сеть. Когда в качестве хоста вы пишите localhost - соединение по умолчанию идет через сокет, когда пишите IP-адрес - через сеть.

Comment: Файл `mysql` в логах почему-то пустой...

Comment: @faoxis mysqld в процессах не видите? При попытке старта какие-то сообщения выводятся?

Comment: В процессах есть. При запуске никаких сообщенийй нет. Рестарт делал - не помогает.

Comment: @faoxis поправил ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста последний параграф - у вас файл сокета в my.cnf точно /tmp/mysql.sock? А не /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?

Comment: У меня вообще такого нет. В папке `/etc/` не оказалось файла `my.cnf`. Но я нашел его в `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Так вот, тут вообще сокет не указан. Я дополнил вопрос целиком содержимым файла `my.cnf`.

Comment: А в /etc/mysql/my.cnf?

Comment: Попробуйте без сокета соединиться, по сети mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p

Comment: Попробовал, возникла ошибка `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: @faoxis О, вот это уже хорошо, значит соединение произошло и сервер вам ответил. Только теперь он говорит о том, что не верный пароль. В общем если кратко, есть два способа соединения с MySQL-сервером, через сокет и через сеть. У вас выключено соединение через сокет и включено сетевое взаимодействие. Когда в качестве хоста вы пишите localhost - соединение по умолчанию идет через сокет, когда пишите IP-адрес - через сеть. Теперь вам нужно разобраться с паролями и доступами к MySQL. Возможно стоит завести новый вопрос.